# c++ rapidjson get add value to exist array

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I tried to create a class which will add a value to a Json array. I tried to do it like this:

```
void functions::Json::SetArray(rapidjson::Document &JsonObj, std::string ArrayName, std::string value)
{
        if (!JsonObj.IsObject()) 
        JsonObj.SetObject();
    

    rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& alloc = JsonObj.GetAllocator();
    
    rapidjson::Value KeyPart;
    KeyPart.SetString(ArrayName.c_str(), alloc);

    rapidjson::Value ValuePart;
    ValuePart.SetString(value.c_str(), alloc);

    rapidjson::Value array(rapidjson::kArrayType);
    
    
    if (!JsonObj["array"].IsNull())
        array = JsonObj["array"];
        

    array.PushBack(ValuePart, alloc);
    JsonObj.AddMember(KeyPart, array, alloc);

}
```

But I have an error:

```
rapidjson/document.h:1218: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding,
Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding,
Allocator>::operator[](const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding,
SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator =
rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>; Encoding =
rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator =
rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]: Assertion
`false' failed.
```

How do I correctly do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at [`rapidjson/document.h:1218`](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/b7734d97c0c011632367f5e3510916828da1346c/include/rapidjson/document.h), this appears to be how it errors when you use the `[]` operator with a member that doesn't exist, probably where you access `JsonObj["array"]`.

If I use `MemberFind` to look up the member first, it works fine for me:

```cpp
rapidjson::Document::MemberIterator existingArray = JsonObj.FindMember("array");
if (existingArray != JsonObj.MemberEnd() && !existingArray->value.IsNull())
    array = existingArray->value;
```